# history of .xsession-errors file and what predated it?

Tags: debian, x11, xorg, history, x-server

History question again. Does anybody know when .xsession-errors were started. The oldest I can find about from `/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg/` is from 2005 which tells about the X11R7.0.0 release . Does anybody know what used to the state before that ?

Comment: Opinion-based questions/answers don't get very far here; you may want to trim off the second question.

Comment: I can't remember *not* having .xsession-errors on Linux (of course I may be wrong). And I think I even had it when I was using dedicated X terminals at university (though I'm not 100% sure). So it must have been there quite early. [X11R5](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R5/) is still around ('91 or so), so I guess you could check.

Comment: It's in the R5 Xsession, but not R4. The R5 has this version tag: `$XConsortium: Xsession,v 1.7 92/08/06 11:08:14 gildea Exp $`. What preceded it was apparently the user session just inherited stderr from the `xdm` daemon, which caused error messages to get lost to /dev/null or in some system log file or on the console where the user couldn't see them.

Comment: As @WumpusQ.Wumbley said, it looks like it's very old (which matches what I thought) but just to corroborate that I am looking at an actual `.xsession-errors` file lying around here in an archived home directory that was last written on 27 October 2000. I could probably find another one somewhere that is closer to the 1992 date but I'd have to dig in offline archives.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley back in those days it was very common for users to run `xconsole` so they could keep track of messages logged to the console. You could turn your comment into an answer, that's as good as it's going to get I think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the old X Consortium upstream sources, it was added in 1991 to replace logging to a system-wide log file that users might not have access to:

https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~alanc/xc-historical/commit/xc/programs/xdm/config/Xsession?id=c1028b1e51d2805d5220e82d04cbbafeab0bb33f

but that had only been introduced a month before, and hadn't made it out into a release yet:

https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~alanc/xc-historical/commit/xc/programs/xdm/config/Xsession?id=43e3c5f5d226637e871dd7615ef40d5f2507edb4

before that, it appears to be as @WumpusQ.Wumbley said in the comment above - it wasn't being captured by the Xsession and instead either lost or logged with the xdm stderr logs.